# Center labels in a matrix and fix row color

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

> Hi. I need to center the phrase "Active user", meaning, I'd like to put it in the middle and not to the right nor the left. One more thing, I need to color those two cells that are in white right now. I do not know why, but they should be in gray.

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,b/.style={text=blue,font=\bfseries}]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
    nodes={minimum size=5ex,anchor=center,draw},
    row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    column 5/.style={nodes={fill=white}},
    column 6/.style={nodes={fill=gray!20}},
    column 7/.style={nodes={fill=gray!20}},
    row 4/.style={nodes={fill=none}},
    column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep={-\pgflinewidth},
    nodes in empty cells,
    ]{
        & $i_{1}$& $i_{2}$ & $i_{3}$ & \dots &$ i_{k}$    & $ i_{a}$  & \dots &$ i_{n}$ \\ 
        $u_{1}$ & &  &   &  &  |[b]| c    &  |[b]| ?  &  &  \\ 
        $u_{2}$ & &  &  &  & |[b]| c & |[b]| c  &   &\\ 
        |[fill=none]|\dots & &   &   &  &   &  &  &    \\ 
        $u_{j}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  & &   \\ 
        $u_{a}$ & &  &  &  & |[b]| c &|[b]| c  & &  \\ 
        \dots& &  &  &  &  &  & &  \\ 
        $u_{6}$ & &  &  &  & |[b]| c & |[b]| c & &  \\
    };
%   \draw[-latex](m-6-9.east)--+(1,0)node[above right]{}|-(m-5-9.east);


    \node[left]at(m-6-1.west){Active user};
%   \draw[latex-] (m-1-6) -- ++ (-1,1) node[above left,align=left]
%   {Item preference score is\\ predicted for active user};
        \draw[latex-] (m-1-7) -- ++ (0,1) node[above right,align=right]
    {Active item};

    \draw[-latex]([xshift=-1pt]m-8-7.south east)--++(0,-1) -| 
    ([xshift=2pt]m-8-6.south west)
    node[pos=0.25,below]{Item similarity}
    node[pos=0.25,above,font=\tiny]{$\mathrm{sim}(i_{k},i_{a})$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Change `node[above right,align=right]` with `node[above]` ... You could also add a `shift=(0.0.2)` or something in these options (inside the "`[]`" like `node[above,shift={(0,0.2)}]`)

Comment: It worked! Thank you

Comment: Welcome ... happy TeXing! I will turn that into an answer if don't find a simmilar dupplicate

Comment: But before, check the coloring question, meaning, the cell that are in white in the colored columns :)

Comment: Yes ... forgot that... What about removing the `row 4/.style={nodes={fill=none}},` ?

Comment: SuPer cool. Turn it into an answer so that I can accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the centering problem you have the code:

```
\draw[latex-] (m-1-7) -- ++ (0,1) node[above right,align=right]
{Active item};
```

That should be:

```
\draw[latex-] (m-1-7) -- ++ (0,1) node[above]
{Active item};
```

(A `node[above,shift={(0,-0.1)}]` could also be useful for negative or positive vertical shift)

For the coloring problem it is caused from the line:

```
row 4/.style={nodes={fill=none}},
```

that is read from the compiler after reading the column (gray) colors and overrides them. As far as I can see this line is not really usefull, so, just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

This matrix being called `(m)` it is enough to anchor the text to the `west` of `(m)` like this `\node[left]at(m.west){Active user};` Your matrix having 8 lines, the text is placed pile between the fourth and fifth columns.

Unless you want it in the center of the last 7 lines?

As for the grey colouring, it is enough to remove the white colouring from line 4.

```
%    row 4/.style={nodes={fill=none}},
```

Although you didn't ask to center the text `Active item` and as @koleygr gave a way to do it, I give another one that uses the `positioning` library. It consists in positioning the text above and using the `edge operation` to draw the arrow between the two nodes.

```
\node[above= 5mm of m-1-7] {Active item}edge[->](m-1-7);
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,b/.style={text=blue,font=\bfseries}]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
    nodes={minimum size=5ex,anchor=center,draw},
    row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    column 5/.style={nodes={fill=white}},
    column 6/.style={nodes={fill=gray!20}},
    column 7/.append style={nodes={fill=gray!20}},
%    row 4/.style={nodes={fill=none}},
    column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep={-\pgflinewidth},
    nodes in empty cells,
    ]{
        & $i_{1}$& $i_{2}$ & $i_{3}$ & \dots &$ i_{k}$    & $ i_{a}$  & \dots &$ i_{n}$ \\ 
        $u_{1}$ & &  &   &  &  |[b]| c    &  |[b]| ?  &  &  \\ 
        $u_{2}$ & &  &  &  & |[b]| c & |[b]| c  &   &\\ 
        |[fill=none]|\dots & &   &   &  &   &  &  &    \\ 
        $u_{j}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  & &   \\ 
        $u_{a}$ & &  &  &  & |[b]| c &|[b]| c  & &  \\ 
        \dots& &  &  &  &  &  & &  \\ 
        $u_{6}$ & &  &  &  & |[b]| c & |[b]| c & &  \\
    };
%   \draw[-latex](m-6-9.east)--+(1,0)node[above right]{}|-(m-5-9.east);


    %\node[left]at(m.west){Active user};
    \node[above= 5mm of m-1-7] {Active item}edge[->](m-1-7);
%   \draw[latex-] (m-1-6) -- ++ (-1,1) node[above left,align=left]
%   {Item preference score is\\ predicted for active user};
        \draw[latex-] (m-1-7) -- ++ (0,1) node[above right,align=right]
    {Active item};

    \draw[-latex]([xshift=-1pt]m-8-7.south east)--++(0,-1) -| 
    ([xshift=2pt]m-8-6.south west)
    node[pos=0.25,below]{Item similarity}
    node[pos=0.25,above,font=\tiny]{$\mathrm{sim}(i_{k},i_{a})$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```